# What are two eleven letter words with distinct letters?

Tags: word, letters

By this I mean two 11 letter words that contain 22 different letters. Do words like these exist?

Comment: My guess would be no, because of the heavy restriction on the vowels. Do you suspect that something like this could exist?

Comment: I originally misread the problem as finding 11 2-letter words, using each letter at most once.  The maximum turns out to be 8: aa, by, de, jo, mm, nu, qi, sh

Comment: Can you please define "word"? What dictionary are we using? Are proper nouns, plurals, conjugations, loanwords, etc. allowed?

Comment: Pretty much anything should work.

Comment: Hello and welcome, the [tour] and [help] should explain what is on topic here. This doesn't look look like a puzzle or about making a puzzle. Maybe you could [edit] that in. As for the question of what you define to be a word, and anything should work... Would you accept these two words I've just made up: Abcdefghijk and Lnmopqrstuv ? That's an extreme example, but  you really should pick a word source to let answerers know if their words would be valid of not.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> No. There does not exist a pair of unique 11-letter English words that both each have 11 different letters and also do not share letters.

My method for finding this answer:

> I grabbed all the 11-letter words from http://www.allscrabblewords.com/11-letter-words/ and made a list of words that contained 11 unique letters. This list has 363 words. I then checked each pair of words to see if any pair didn't share letters. Unfortunately, this check revealed 0 word pairs.

The OP asked a secondary question, and my answer is:

> Question: Which 2 11-letter words contain the most distinct letters
>  It took less time than I expected to run through all combinations, but I found 15 pairs of words that have 20 distinct letters. The first pair that also each contain 11 distinct letters are:
> downrightly lumberjacks

Comment: Would you be able to use this method to find two words that contain the greatest number of distinct letters possible?

Comment: It would take a lot longer because the full 11 letter word list is rather large. Finding the greatest number of distinct letters from 2 11-letter words that each have 11 distinct letters is a much quicker ask.

Comment: I did the same thing as Joel and got the same answer (too slow though).  @HyperioxX - Do you mind if I ask what the goal is?  It feels like you're trying to do something specific with this.

Comment: It’s for an eleven letter wordle game, and I’m trying to figure out the best combination of two words to start with. Ideally I don’t really care about q, x, z, and j, but whichever two words cover the most letters are ideal.

Comment: I ran this search against a larger word list (called "british-english-insane", with more than 1111 words of exactly 11 letters), no hits there either.

Comment: My favorite word pair, missing only fjqvxz, is patchworked stumblingly