# Two 10-letter words consisting of 20 unique letters?

Tags: wordplay, optimization, letters, wordle, pangram

I'm looking for two words, 10 letters each, 20 unique letters. Below are my by-hand attempts.

1. https://www.wordunscrambler.net/word-list/10-letter-words-with-no-repeating-letters Find words with 3 or fewer vowels including Y, increasing the chance of a hit on the 2nd word's search. (More comprehensive lists at https://www.morewords.com/unique-https://www.morewords.com/unique-lettersletters)
2. https://hellowordl.net/ Type it into the 10-letter game to check that it's not too esoteric. The actual site I use it for is https://solitaired.com/phrazle, which showcases as long as 11-letter words from time to time.
3. To quickly isolate missing letters, https://chat.openai.com/ with the following text: print the alphabet in full. on a second line print the letters in WORD in alpha order, then on a third line print the remaining letters. Double check that the final line is indeed 16 letters and contains none of the letters in WORD.
4. https://wordsmith.org/anagram/advanced.html: feed in "remaining 16 letters" blob with specs "Min. # of letters in a word: 9" / "Show candidate words only: Yes".

For my troubles, I've gotten to 19 unique letters in a few ways: between a 10-letter and a 9-letter (first paragraph below), and between two 10-letters with a doubled letter (the capital at end of the blob; second paragraph). A while ago, I was gifted two 11-letter words with 20 unique letters (L+R doubled): Downrightly Lumberjacks. This clearly affected my searches; very little [nothing; below] outside of these terms bore fruit. (Found the source: [What are two eleven letter words with distinct letters?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115203/what-are-two-eleven-letter-words-with-distinct-letters), Downrightly-Lumberjacks and Patchworked-Stumblingly.)

playwright bcdefijkmnosquvzx Subjoined [never trust AI, this isn't even correct: the I is there twice]
lumberjack dfghinopqstvwxyz Downshift

lumberjack dfghinopqstvwxyzL Downlights
lumberjack dfghinopqstvwxyzS Downshifts/Fishponds/Townships

Hell with it, I also got a few hits for 8-letter words from wordsmith, but I stopped keeping track after the first few hits for time's and sanity's sake.
complexify abdghjknqrstuvwz Draughts
dwarfishly bcdegjkmnopqtuvxz Computed/Document/Uncombed/Judgment
flyweights abcdijkmnopqruvxz Moribund/Cupboard/Backdrop
fosterling abcdhjkmpquvwxyz Humpback

A quick final net search turned up [Word sets with no repeating letters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8212/word-sets-with-no-repeating-letters) with 19 letters for Blacksmith Gunpowders (hello wordl won't accept gunpowdery).

Comment: A search of [a wordlist derived from Google Books](https://github.com/hackerb9/gwordlist) turned up zero results for 20 letters (and 77 results for 19 letters).

Comment: @codewarrior0 Post the first 20 for gits and shiggles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Be warned: the GBooks wordlist is full of misspellings, OCR malfunctions, and other nonsense. It is also missing a handful of plural forms.

Pairs of 10-letter words, using 19 unique letters, ordered by frequency. (Missing letters in parentheses.) [Duplicate letters in brackets.]

```
BACKGROUND SYMPATHIZE (fjlqvwx) [A]
BACKGROUND POLYTHEISM (fjqvwxz) [O]
BACKGROUND POLYETHISM (fjqvwxz) [O]
BANKRUPTCY SELFMOVING (dhjqwxz) [N]
FITZGERALD MONKEYCUPS (bhjqvwx) [E]
SUBJECTING HYPODERMAL (fkqvwxz) [E]
SUBJECTING HOMEWARDLY (fkpqvxz) [E]
CONJUGATED FRUMPISHLY (bkqvwxz) [U]
STRICKLAND HYPOZEUGMA (bfjqvwx) [A]
MODULATING SHIPWRECKY (bfjqvxz) [I]
JUXTAPOSED CHARMINGLY (bfkqvwz) [A]
JUDGMENTAL IXOBRYCHUS (fkpqvwz) [U]
JUDGMENTAL SCYPHIFORM (bkqvwxz) [M]
JUDGMENTAL SHIPWRECKY (bfoqvxz) [E]
TRANSFIXED PLOUGHBACK (jmqvwyz) [A]
HYPNOTIZED LUMBERJACK (fgqsvwx) [E]
SHOCKINGLY DUMBWAITER (fjpqvxz) [I]
ADJUNCTIVE HYGROPLASM (bfkqwxz) [A]
METHYLDOPA SPRINGBUCK (fjqvwxz) [P]
UNWORTHILY GOBSMACKED (fjpqvxz) [O]
[...]
```

No pairs of 11 letter words with more than 20 unique letters were found. Those with exactly 20 unique letters:

```
PREDICTABLY SHOWJUMPING (fkqvxz) [IP]
SYMPATHIZED BACKFLOWING (jqruvx) [AI]
SYMPATHIZED FURBELOWING (cjkqvx) [EI]
VALEDICTORY SHOWJUMPING (bfkqxz) [IO]
SYMPATHIZER BACKFLOWING (djquvx) [AI]
CRYSTALIZED SHOWJUMPING (bfkqvx) [IS]
SULPHYDRATE BACKFLOWING (jmqvxz) [AL]
SYMPATHIQUE BACKFLOWING (djrvxz) [AI]
QUAVERINGLY SCHIMPFWORT (bdjkxz) [IR]
BACKFLOWING HYPOSTERNUM (djqvxz) [NO]
SCHIMPFWORT SQUEAKINGLY (bdjvxz) [IS]
```

No pairs of 12 letter words with more than 20 unique letters were found. Those with exactly 20 unique letters:

```
LEXICOGRAPHY DUMBSTRICKEN (fjqvwz) [CEIR]
UNFORGIVABLY MACKINTOSHED (jpqwxz) [AINO]
ADJUNCTIVELY SCHOMBURGKIA (fpqwxz) [ACIU]
MYXOCEPHALUS POWDERINGTUB (fjkqvz) [EOPU]
```

Comment: I obtained similar results, max 19 letters and no 20.

Comment: Two of those words were juxtaposed charmingly, but two others were merely conjugated frumpishly.

Comment: I consider myself both lexicography dumbstricken and unforgivably mackintoshed.

Answer (score 11):

In *Making the Alphabet Dance*, p.56, Ross Eckler gives the two 10-letter words *blacksmith, gunpowdery* from Webster's unabridged.

Comment: Mentioned in OP. Gunpowdery not accepted by most wordle clones, at least the two I use.

Comment: @user87072 If there’s a particular dictionary that answers are required to come from, you should link to it in the question.

Comment: @Sneftel Honestly, I never know what to say to this. My best but unknown answer is "whatever 'solitaired dot com slash phrazle' uses." So I instead point people towards the only wordlist of which I am aware: YAWL. https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 4):

I did a computer search on a large wordlist.  I used the OSPD4 Scrabble dictionary unioned with the 2+2+3lem list from version 6.0.2 of 12dicts.

I found no two 10-letter words with 20 unique letters, nor a 9-letter word with a 11-letter word, or a 8-letter word with a 12-letter word.  Let's see some near misses.

These pairs of words have 21 letters total, but only 20 unique letters, because they either share a letter or one of them has a duplicate letter.

- cred**i**tably showjump**i**ng (10, 11)
- hypnotiz**e**d lumb**e**rjacks (10, 11)
- sk**e**tch**e**d unforgivably (8, 12)
- b**a**ckflip dr**a**ughtswomen (8, 13)
- backw**oo**dsmen uprightly (12, 9)

Here's the list of pairs of words with 19 letters total and all unique.  I bolded the pairs where both words are in the smaller 2+2+3lem wordlist, suggesting that these are more common words.

- aftershock jumpingly (10, 9)
- backgrounds whitefly (11, 8)
- backlights jurywomen (10, 9)
- **badmouth flyspecking** (8, 11)
- **badmouthing flyspeck** (11, 8)
- birdwatches longjump (11, 8)
- blackgums hypnotized (9, 10)
- **blacksmith gunpowder** (10, 9)
- **blameworthy duckpins** (11, 8)
- blameworthy kingcups (11, 8)
- **blaspheming ductwork** (11, 8)
- boschvark impudently (9, 10)
- bowingly deutschmark (8, 11)
- buckramed flyposting (9, 10)
- buckwheats rompingly (10, 9)
- bumpkinly dogwatches (9, 10)
- bumpkinly godfathers (9, 10)
- bumpkinly shortwaved (9, 10)
- **bylaws ??????????ing** (6, 13)
- campgrounds whitefly (11, 8)
- depluming throwbacks (9, 10)
- disjunct flexography (8, 11)
- **downshift lumberjack** (9, 10)
- duplexing throwbacks (9, 10)
- endolymph jackfruits (9, 10)
- endolymphs jackfruit (10, 9)
- fancyworks uplighted (10, 9)
- **fightbacks jurywomen** (10, 9)
- flackery showjumping (8, 11)
- flyspecking warmouth (11, 8)
- frowsting humpbacked (9, 10)
- fumbled patchworking (7, 12)
- fumbles patchworking (7, 12)
- fumbling patchworked (8, 11)
- fumingly patchworked (8, 11)
- gawkishly procumbent (9, 10)
- **hogbacks imprudently** (8, 11)
- holdbacks putrefying (9, 10)
- howdying lumberjacks (8, 11)
- **humpbacks overflying** (9, 10)
- humpbacks toweringly (9, 10)
- jumbled patchworking (7, 12)
- jumbles patchworking (7, 12)
- jumbling patchworked (8, 11)
- jumpingly shortwaved (9, 10)
- jumpingly throwbacks (9, 10)
- longjumped whitracks (10, 9)
- misgrafted punchbowl (10, 9)
- musingly patchworked (8, 11)
- patchworks unmixedly (10, 9)
- **playwrights uncombed** (11, 8)
- **punchbowls taxidermy** (10, 9)
- **sympathized wrongful** (11, 8)
- throwbacks unmixedly (10, 9)

Comment: [fumblings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fumblings) patchworked (9, 11)

Comment: Hahaha I finally figured out bylaws ??????????ing. mf'in amazing